# Failed to set session description on WebRTC

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, webrtc

I set the remote description, callback `didSetSessionDescriptionWithError` got hit, & showing the error :

```
- (void)processAnswer:(NSString *)sdpAnswer connectionId:(NSString *)connectionId {
    //NSParameterAssert(sdpAnswer);
    NSParameterAssert(connectionId);

    NBMPeerConnection *connection = self.connectionMap[connectionId];
    __block __weak RTCPeerConnection* peerConnection = connection.peerConnection;
    RTCSessionDescription *description = [[RTCSessionDescription alloc] initWithType:RTCSdpTypeAnswer sdp:sdpAnswer];
   [connection.peerConnection setRemoteDescription:description completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    [self peerConnection:peerConnection didSetSessionDescriptionWithError:error];
}];
}
```

after call getting this error.

Error Domain=org.webrtc.RTCPeerConnection Code=-1 "SessionDescription is NULL."

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Did you check `description` after calling `initWithType`? Anyway, it seems like i'm using another library so i cannot help you.

Comment: have you managed to fix this problem, Avinash?

Comment: @AvinashVaghasiya What is the solution here, getting same error

Comment: @AvinashVaghasiya Any chance you could answer this question with your solution? I have the same problem. (if you're prepared to ask for free help imo you should give it as well)

Answer (score 3):

I had faced the same error and fixed it by adding "\n" to the end of the of the Offer string. Hope this helps.

Comment: This actually helped me, Thank you. I was sending the sdp and even logging it on the server to compare it on the receiving side and it was exactly the same but adding the "\n" at the end and re-creating it on the receiving side worked.